# Which is the correct translation for "I went to the bathroom twice": 去了厕所两次 or 去厕所两次了?

Tags: particles, word-order

Which one is correct please?

If I try to translate:

*I went to the bathroom twice.*

- 去了厕所两次
- 去厕所两次了

Comment: Maybe 趟 is better than 次 in this context?

Comment: I think it sounds more natural with the number of times coming before the destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb particle '了' after '去' in "去了厕所两次" indicates the verb '去' is completed, so "去了(went to) 厕所两次 (the bathroom twice)"  is the correct translation

The final particle '了' after '去厕所两次'  emphasizes 两次 --> "两次**了**" = "twice **already**"

But '了' here can also function as a verb particle that indicates the verb phrase 去厕所两次 as a completed action --> "[**去**]厕所两次[**了**]" = "[**went to**] the bathroom twice"

Both translations are valid, but the first one is more literal (word for word translation)

Comment: So in other words, the later has the more nuanced meaning, "as of now, I've been to the bathroom twice"?

Comment: @小奥利奥 Yes, it can, depending on the content.